# docker ps is running the containers

Tags: docker

I want to know what containers I have available and seems like the command `docker ps` do it, but this command is also running the containers.

You can see in the picture the status of the containers "Up less than a second" meaning that they has just been started with the command `docker ps`.

[image]

What command can I run to just see the containers without running them?

Best regards.

Comment: Do you see high cpu usage from the docker processes ? if the containers get restarted multiple times in a second , this might results in high CPU usage . This is a way to test the scenario which is proposed by @Donentolon.

Comment: `docker ps` will not start any container by itself. But, if the docker socket is set on demand, the first time the docker cli will try to use it, the system will start the docker daemon, and if the container are set to restart, you will have this kind of result: all running container started few second ago.

Answer (score 2):

`docker ps` shouldn't run the containers. In the unlikely event that it does, I would go through the standard steps of reporting Docker bugs: Reproduction steps, Docker version, etc. If it really is a bug, you could roll back to an older Docker version and surely there are a bunch where `docker ps` does not contain such critical bugs.

Most likely the problem is specific to your environment. The easy way to confirm this is to try the same commands on a different machine or VM. On my machine, for instance, `docker ps` does not run containers - once you find a machine that also has correct `docker ps` behavior you can then start comparing them to find the difference.

Maybe you have `docker ps` aliased to something else or something like that? There are other ways to check container status, such as Portainer and ctop. I think these probably rely on the same logic as `docker ps`, but you should see if they have the same issue in any case.

By the way, the status is just the status of the container. It could be that the container is failing a few seconds after launch, and being restarted by Docker, which is why you see the message. Try running a standard container like `ubuntu` or `hello-world` with simple parameters (definitely without `--restart=always` or `--rm`), and see if that also gets "restarted". My bet is it won't, unless you have a serious misconfiguration/Docker bug (in which case do a clean install of older Docker version).

Comment: `docker ps` could "start" all the container if the service is "on demand". Like when the cli try to make a request on the docker socket, if the service is not running, the service will be started.

Comment: @jmaitrehenry I think that would fall under "serious misconfiguration/Docker bug". Simply asking what containers are running should not run the containers.

Comment: It's how the docker service could be configured using systemd, when someone make a call to a socket, systemd could start the service on demand. It's not really docker but more how the system handle the socket and some OS configuration.

Comment: @jmaitrehenry That's a fair point. I suppose that's something for the user to consider when implementing this kind of systemd on-demand start. Still seems like a very strange setup to me, I would assume any on-demand service would include some logic so that merely checking status doesn't count as "demand".

Answer (score 0):

It's probably too late to suggest a solution, but I'll add this in case anyone else faces the same issue that I did.

Try running:

```
sudo systemctl enable docker.service
```

Comment: Please add also an explanation. If the Docker Daemon is not running at startup, it will be started by the docker.socket, as soon as the socket is used. Here the `docker ps` command invokes a request to the docker socket, which starts the daemon, which than starts matching containers (e.g. `restart: always`). This causes this behaviour at least for the first command after a reboot,

Answer (score 0):

`docker ps` does not start any containers. It is more likely a misconfiguration of your Docker setup. If the Docker Daemon is not running at startup, it will be started by the docker.socket, as soon as the socket is used. Here the `docker ps` command invokes a request to the Docker socket, which starts the daemon, which than starts matching containers (e.g. restart: always). This causes this behaviour at least for the first command after a reboot.

Please ensure that you Docker Daemon is started on each boot, by running

```bash
sudo systemctl enable docker.service
sudo systemctl start docker.service
```

Answer (score -1):

To directly answer your question:

> What command can I run to just see the containers without running them?

You can also run the command: `docker container list`

Which results in this:

[image]

Comment: `docker ps` and `docker container list` is the same, the `docker ps` was the initial way to list container.

Comment: @jmaitrehenry duh. Hence the "also" in my comment. Idea being if he's having issues with one specific command `ps` then he can try/test with another command to do the same. I didn't create multiple ways to see containers, Docker did, I'm passing along the commands to the question asker.